# Count distinct values where count of another value = 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Given

```
------------------------------
|id | val1 | val2 | date     |
______________________________
1     10      2     1990-10-02
2     10      3     1990-10-02
3     1       1     1990-10-02
4     21      1     1990-10-02
5     30      3     1990-10-02
6     30      1     1990-10-02
```

I want to have in results the row with id 3 and 4 because they have only one val1 if we group by val1.

How to achieve this?
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) WHERE

Comment: So the final two columns are irrelevant?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` for this:

```
select t.*
from t
group by val1
having count(*) = 1;
```

In general, I am opposed to having an aggregation query with unaggregated columns in the `select`.  However, it is fine in this case because the `count(*)` guarantees that there is only one matching row.

Note:  this will not work in other databases.

Comment: Your answer is almost what I need. I have something like this in laravel
where('created_at','like',$today."%")->distinct('ip')->count('ip'); 
https://jsfiddle.net/L7zpgbku/ - here is the table. I want to use this query to get the bounce rate

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.id <> x.id AND y.val1 = x.val2
          WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```